# Difference between "real" and "unsolved-mysteries"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There exists the tag [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real) which currently has a [wiki](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/real/info) of

> A tag used to specify real-world puzzles which usually do not have a solution at the time of posting. This can include widely-known puzzles that have remained unsolved for some time.
>
> This tag is most generally used when posting a real-world puzzle/mystery, and as such, the ability of the poster to provide additional details may be limited. It can represent a widely-known unsolved mystery, for which there is often a low expectation of the community actually finding an answer.

There also exists the [unsolved-mysteries](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unsolved-mysteries) with a [wiki](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/unsolved-mysteries/info) that currently reads:

> Current unsolved real-world puzzle
>
> Some puzzle are made by some brilliant minds and are worth sharing.
>   There often is no known solution and sometimes no proof that is possible.

Should these be merged?  If not, how are they different?  When would you tag a question with one, but not the other?

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4669/).

Comment: I feel like they *should* be different, but I have a hard time thinking of something which would be under [tag:unsolved-mysteries] that isn't also under [tag:real].  But the former feels like a better tag than the latter.  Maybe we need to merge them into a [tag:real-unsolved-mysteries] tag?

Answer (score 3):

There are puzzles like [Logic behind numeric sequence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/38310/19765),
which are abstract mental exercises
where the poster claims not to know the answer. 
ISTM that it might be appropriate
to tag these with [unsolved-something](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unsolved-something) (but definitely not [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real)).

Then again, they both smell of meta. 
What sort of person would be an expert in real-world puzzles
or unsolved mysteries?

Comment: I agree that both tags are pretty meta, particularly the unsolved-mysteries.  After all, answering a question with that tag would also remove that tag.  It could also be argued that if there is an unsolved-... tag, then all questions users here make can have that tag until another user answers it.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that the only difference is that the [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real) tag can be a mystery which is solved, whereas [unsolved-mysteries](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unsolved-mysteries) is specifically unsolved,

> Personally I don't think they should be merged, but they are similar

Comment: So, does that mean that every "unsolved-mysteries" should also be tagged "real"?